# unexpected behavior of shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm quite confused When I try to ouput some patterns with `*` in shell.The code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    tmpstr=""
    for ((c=1;c<=i;c++))
    do
            tmpstr=$tmpstr'*'
    done
    echo $tmpstr  #add some string after tmpstr will work
done
```

The output shows me the result of `ls` command in each line which is unexpected. And the code will works fine if I add any string after `echo $tmpstr`.For example,`echo $tmpstr" "`  .So how to understand this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is generating the following for tmpStr

```
*
**
***
etc.
```

which results in the following echo statements

```
echo *
echo **
echo ***
etc.
```

The shell interprets the * as a wildcard and expands it by listing all the files in the current directory.

Note that if you put quotes around the shell variable:

```
echo "$tmpstr"
```

The shell does not expand the wildcard characters and the output is

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

Comment: I think this is the point.But a space after the string will make the wild card not work still is a mistery.

Comment: I don't follow.  You state that the code works fine with echo $tmpStr" ".  As you have written this, there is no wildcard, just a space.

Comment: I mean `echo $tmpstr" "` inside the first loop not the inner one.

Comment: @Young, well you can see for yourself by running `echo *` and then `echo *" "`. In the first case the shell treats `*` as a wildcard and expands it. In the second case the contiguous bits `*` and `" "` are concatenated into a single word `* `, and the `*` within the word is not expanded

Comment: @EJK `echo * `(with space after) and `echo *`(no space after) give the same output.But in my case they didn't.

Comment: @1_CR - Nicely explained.

Comment: @Young With `echo * ` the final space is not treated as part of the "word" `*`; with `echo *" "` the double-quotes force the shell to treat it as a normal part of the word. If you had any files with names ending in space, `echo *" "` would list them, but you don't so the wildcard doesn't get expanded. Try this: `touch 'foo '; echo *" "` (and then try your script with the `echo $tmpstr" "` again).

Comment: @EJK 1_CR Gordon Davisson,OK.I got you.I 've understood the the shell's quotes.Thanks all and answer accepted.